# Resolving a type in autofac

Tags: autofac

I have the following setup:

```
builder.Register<Configuration>(
   c => ConfigurationFile.Load<Configuration>(filename)
).SingleInstance();
```

Somewhere else in my program I have

```
void Dispose()
{
    ConfigurationFile.Save(Configuration, @"c:\config.cfg");
}
```

How do I resolve `Configuration` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you Build your Component Container, there is Resolve method which can be used to inject all your dependencies automatically. From the scope defined in your question it is not clear what kind of relations you have between classes and Component Container. But hope this example helps

```
builder.Register<Configuration>(c => 
        ConfigurationFile.Load<Configuration>(filename)).SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().SingleInstance();
return builder.Build();
```

Main window:

```
public class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow(Configuration configuration)
    {

    }
}
```

Some bootstrapper or factory or whatever:

```
public MainWindow GetMainWindow()
{
    container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
}
```

Comment: Where does `container` come from in the `MainWindow`?

Comment: MainWindow doesn't know anything about Container. Container resolves MainWindow instance with its dependencies. Container itself usually comes from the same place as all your registrations - from some startup routine. Autofac has builtin interfaces which you could inject along with your own. e.g. ILifetimeScope, from which you also could resolve whatever you want.